# Transmit Audio/Music Between Phones

Tags: voip, rtp, cisco, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I have peculiar request where I need to transmit audio between Cisco IP phones when they are on a call. The reason I am doing this is so that I can get call quality reports for determining audio quality of a call. However, I am absolutely stuck right now. Is it possible to do something like this through Jtapi? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

As of now, I have tried Cisco Media Terminal (CTI port) and used commands like RTPRx and RTPTx to receive and transmit rtp streams with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You could just launch Wireshark to capture the call and then use the Wireshark VoIP/RTP tool to analyze the quality. (I don't know it's exact name, it can be found in the menu)

Comment: I know how to analyze call quality. My question was to actually transmit a sample audio (like an audio file) to an existing call so it would seem like a person is actually talking on the phone.